# mysql error 1062 during alter table modify column

Tags: mysql, qt, qsqlquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    col1 VARCHAR(256),
    UNIQUE INDEX t1_col1_index (col1)
)
```

I'm trying to modify the col1 type using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY COLUMN col1 varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

However, I run into this duplication error:

> error: ("1062", "QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement", "Duplicate entry '+123456789' for key 't1_col1_index'")

I initially thought it could be because two or more rows might 'contain' similar value for col1 and on changing varchar length the data gets truncated but then I found out that data truncation wouldn't even allow the query to go through. Any pointers on what could be causing this?

EDIT (Resolved): Truncation does happen when @@sql_mode is not set with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. This was causing the error.

Comment: The issue may caused by collation of column, when the previous collation is case sensitive and you try to change it to case insensitive.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer! Is there a way to verify this, or dig more deeper into this? The reason I'm asking this is because I'm just storing numbers in col1, with occasional '+' symbol. Trying to see what might have caused this issue.

Comment: Also, shouldn't unicode collation handle such case sensitive issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reducing the length of a varchar column that is controlled by a `UNIQUE` constraint.

This is risky business. Oversize data will be silently trimed (unless you have the `@@sql_mode` set to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` in which case an error will be raised). This probably generates duplicates, which cause the error to be raised by your `UNIQUE` constraint.

You can check the max length of the values in your column with :

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(col1)) FROM t1:
```

Comment: You're mixing `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE`.

Comment: @stickybit : I was starting to wonder... So changing the collation does not generate data conversion, right ?

Comment: @stickybit I updated my anwer to focus on the size reduction of the column

Comment: As I understand it, no. But changing the collation might change the cases when two strings are considered equal. So in general your answer may be right. But without sample data and the collation before the change that's hardly testable.

Comment: That is not entirely true. If I change the varchar to a length smaller than the max char_length of a column the sql query fails with the following error:

ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'col1' at row 9322

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right. I had the @@sql_mode set to STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. This doesn't allow the data truncation and throws this error, but when we disable it, I do get the duplicate entry error.

Comment: @DjokerS : mmm interesting, I added a mention to this parameter in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is work.

Try to check the table `t1`.

```
select count(1) from t1 where col1 = 123456789
```

Now if count is greater than one then try to remove the other one and leave only one record.

Then try to run your statement again.

Reminder:
Do `back up` first before removing.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the problem statement. It's a unique index. There's no duplicate entry.

Comment: How about this way `ALTER TABLE t1
ALTER COLUMN col1 varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` You can temporarily remove the index first then put it back when `ALTER` has been done.

Comment: If unicode collation scheme considers two values as same, shouldn't that still be a problem when I try to create an index after changing column type? Basically, there are two values that are equal according to this collation which are now present in the table, creating an index on this should fail, right?